# Evaluating $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\lfloor 1+ \sqrt{1+x}\rfloor}}$

Tags: calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How can I solve this integral?

$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{\lfloor 1+ \sqrt{1+x}\rfloor}}$$

Comment: Where did this integral come up? Is it an exercise?

Comment: It's an excersise of a calculus book; the author is Álvaro Pinzón @rubik. He gives a solution for that integral making the variable change $u=\sqrt(\lfloor 1+\sqrt(1+x)\rfloor)$ but I'm not sure of his 'solution'.

Answer (score 4):

There does not exist an indefinite integral because of the intermediate value theorem for derivatives (Darboux's theorem).

If you are given a concrete interval over which to integrate, the question is trivial, because the function is piecewise constant.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I was thinking about something like this. A function which is a derivative can only have essential discontinuities.

Comment: piecewise constant?

Comment: @Shakespeare: Look at the graph of the function: https://www.desmos.com/screenshot/kvypbeffou

Comment: @Shakespeare I think he means it's constant over the entire interval except at most a countably infinite number of points and the function is discontinuous at each of those points.

Comment: @rubik Oh, sorry, I missed the floor in there.

Comment: If the function is piecewise constant (with every finite interval involving only a finite number of values), then surely it has a piecewise linear, and continuous, antiderivative.

Comment: Such a piecewise linear function is not differentiable at the points where the slope changes.

Comment: Certainly, but it does give the correct values for the indefinite integral, and that is what is required here.

Comment: Yes, thats true in the sense that $\int_a^b f(x)dx = F(b)-F(a)$ for such a piecewise linear function $F$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice for any integer $n \ge 2$ and $x \ge 0$,

$$\begin{align}
\left\lfloor 1 + \sqrt{1+x}\right\rfloor = n
&\iff n \le 1 + \sqrt{1+x} < n+1\\
&\iff x \in [ (n-1)^2 - 1, n^2 - 1 )
\end{align}$$
To perform the integral over some interval $[0,X]$ where $X > 0$, you just need to split the interval $[0,X]$ to intervals of the form $[(n-1)^2-1, n^2 - 1)$. Let $N = \left\lfloor 1 + \sqrt{1+X}\right\rfloor$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^X \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left\lfloor 1 + \sqrt{1+x}\right\rfloor}}
&= \left( \sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\int_{(n-1)^2-1}^{n^2-1} + \int_{(N-1)^2-1}^X\right)
\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left\lfloor 1 + \sqrt{1+x}\right\rfloor}}\\
&= \sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{2n-1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{X - (N-1)^2 + 1}{\sqrt{N}}
\end{align}
$$